# How can I use XMLHttpRequest to read a file from the filesystem?

Tags: javascript

In this code I am trying to open a file (skills.xml) which is in the same folder as the current page, but it's returning null.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function loadXMLDoc() {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    alert(xmlhttp.readyState + "       " + xmlhttp.status);

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "skills.xml", true);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        alert(xmlhttp.readyState + "       " + xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            myFunction(xmlhttp); 
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: are you loading the page containing this code locally (i.e. file:///) or through a server (http[s]://) ?

Comment: yes it is locally.. are there any issues ?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work. look at the name XML**Http**Request - it has http right there in the middle - that means it uses `http` protocol not `file`

Comment: there is any solution for that ? like to open the xml locally ?

Comment: @JaromandaX _Despite its name, `XMLHttpRequest` can be used to retrieve any type of data, not just XML, and it supports protocols other than HTTP (including `file` and `ftp`)._ [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: @MattJacob do you know how can I fix it ? I was looking a solution using jQuery. Do you have another suggestion ?

Comment: you need to use a sync pattern locally, because on file:///, status is always zero... `xmlhttp.open("GET", "skills.xml", false);` then kill the orsc function, then add `return xmlhttp.responseText; ` to the end of the function, you don't need myFunction anymore...

Comment: I changed the URL with http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml, but is the same result.

Comment: Browsers are very wary of allowing filesystem operations.  You may be running into a security obstacle.  Research what it takes for your individual browser to allow supporting this.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me for a long time, and the problem is that i didn't have a server, i was just visualizing the file in the file system. If you are using VSCode there is a simple work-around to this: you can install the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer&ssr=false#overview) extension and run the html file on the server using the button in the bar at the bottom that says "Go Live". **Note**: you might need to reload the IDE.

(P.S.: i know it's been long since this question was asked but feel free to tell me if you found another way to deal with the problem or if there were other problems)

Comment: This was kind of what comments were saying, glad you fixed the issue